# Is there a word/phrase to describe torching dead bodies?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word to describe torching a dead body; does *cremate* suit?

Comment: I think good to explain *cremate* and why you are concerned about using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Merriam Webster, **cremate** is the right word.

Definition:

> to reduce to ashes by burning

Link: [Cremate- Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cremate)